# Binary storage of numbers with overflow bits...how's the format called?

Tags: numbers, protocols, binary-serialization

For a serialization/protocol format I have to encode unsigned numbers up to unsigned 64bit integer in a space-saving way that should still be easy to implement (meaning, I'm not looking for a dedicated compression algorithm). I was thinking about the following:

```
if n<128  
    take bits 0..6 for representing n, set overflow bit 7 to 0
    store one byte
if n>=128 and n<16384
    take bits 0..6 of byte 1 as bits 0..6 of n, set overflow bit 7 of byte 1 to 1
    take bits 0..6 of byte 2 as bits 7..13 of n, set overflow bit 7 of byte 2 to 0
    store byte 1 followed by byte 2
 if n>=16384 and n<2^21
    ...set overflow bit 7 of byte 2 to 1... (and so on)
```

I have two questions about this:

1. How is this format called? Where can I look up implementations?
2. This is for a binary protocol that will be sent over sockets, where small numbers <128 will be sent very often. Do you think the extra processing is worth it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some more research I've finally found it. It's called 'variable-length quantity' and used in MIDI and ASN.1 (see [Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity))

To answer my other question, I'm tending to believe it isn't worth the processing overhead but I'm still pondering about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not the same as, but similar to UTF-8.

**Edit**

BTW: try and choose a known protocol. UTF-8, Huffman encoding...

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Sure, I want to use a known protocol, that's why I'm asking. I'm aware of the similarity to UTF8 but this is for numbers. Using a byte-based format with 7 bits for encoding and 1 overflow bit is rather natural and I find it unlikely that I've just invented it. Has no one seen this before?